# Tkinter Notebook widget

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am trying to create multiple tabs using `ttk.Notebook` widget. I am creating a simple multi-tab notepad. but I don't know how to deal with the NoteBook widget. but when I click on save button it overrides all tabs text area that because of I declared there `self.tx.get("1.0","end-1c")`.all written file change their text according to last text. Thanks for helping me

```
    #-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    import tkinter.ttk as ttks
    from tkinter import LEFT,RIGHT,X,Y,BOTH
    class MainUI:
        def __init__(self,master):
            self.master = master

            self.nb = ttks.Notebook(self.master)
            self.nb.pack(fill='both',expand=1)

            self.name = ttks.Entry(self.master)
            self.name.pack()
            self.save_tab = ttks.Button(self.master,text="save",command=lambda:self.save_file()).pack()
            #tab1
            self.page1 = ttks.Frame(self.nb)
            self.txt = ttks.tkinter.Text(self.page1)
            self.txt.pack(fill='both',expand=1)
            self.nb.add(self.page1,text="tab1")

            self.page2 = ttks.Frame(self.nb)
            self.nb.add(self.page2,text="tab2")
            self.master.bind('',self.add_tabs)

        def add_tabs(self,event):
            self.page_name = ttks.Frame(self.nb)
            self.tx = ttks.tkinter.Text(self.page_name)
            self.tx.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
            self.nb.add(self.page_name,text="pagename")

        def save_file(self):
            self.fname = self.name.get()
            self.txtinput = self.tx.get("1.0","end-1c")
            with open(self.fname,'w') as f:
                f.write(self.txtinput)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        root = ttks.tkinter.Tk()
        root.title('Tabs>>')
        root.geometry('500x500')
        MainUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image]

[image]

after Implementing below code got following Exception
[image]

Comment: *"click on save button it overrides all tabs text area"*: It's not clear what you mean here. [Edit] your Question and explain in detail, even showing example output.

Comment: Did you say: *Click on `[Save]` with name `"name1.txt"`* will override the content of the existing file `"name.txt"` with the content of the last `ttks.tkinter.Text(...`?

Comment: yes its override all previous files

Comment: Treid your code and could not reproduce your issue. Please make sure, code you posts actually behaves as you claim.

Comment: it is the same code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `add_tabs`, you are replacing the value of `self.tx` each time that a new tab is added. I.e. you only remember the last created text widget. You need to:

- store all the text widgets you create (i.e. using a list)
- have some means to find the text widget in foreground, e.g. by looking at the active tab or the focused widget.

In `__init__`, add:

```
self.txs = [] # "s" suffix to discern list and elements
```

in `add_tabs`, use:

```
tx = ttks.tkinter.Text(self.page_name)
self.txs.append(tx) # append to list
tx.pack(...)
```

in `save_file`, use:

```
tab_index = self.nb.index(self.nb.select())
tx = self.txs[tab_index + 1] # may need to adjust depending on how much "static" tabs are in front
txtinput = self.tx.get("1.0", "end-1c")
# ...
```

Comment: i got it what you wanna say but please will you explain with example should i make Notebook widget to list or frame list?

Comment: I implemented your example into my code but got an exception... It is too long so I update in question

Comment: Forgot the parens after ``self.nb.select``, sorry. The exception clearly indicates the erroneous line. Generally if using functions that are new to you, it is a good idea to have a look at the docs.https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#notebook

Comment: Thank I fixed my problem I created list of tabs and text widgets but now fall into another problem.